# undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass for saas hw2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run an app on Rails, for a saas course, homework 2. Whenever I refresh the page, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in MoviesController#index

undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: C:/Sites/RailsProjects/hw2_rottenpotatoes

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:24:in `block in index'
app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:23:in `each'
app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:23:in `index'
```

My `movies_controller.rb` file:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    id = params[:id] # retrieve movie ID from URI route
    @movie = Movie.find(id) # look up movie by unique ID
  end

  def index
    redirect = false

    if params[:sort]
      @sorting = params[:sort]
    elsif session[:sort]
      @sorting = session[:sort]
      redirect = true
    end

    if redirect
      redirect_to movies_path(:sort => @sorting, :ratings => @ratings)
    end

    Movie.find(:all, :order => @sorting ? @sorting : :id).each do |mv|
      if @ratings.keys.include? mv[:rating]
        (@movies ||= [ ]) << mv
      end
    end

    session[:sort] = @sorting
    session[:ratings] = @ratings
  end

  def new
      # default: render 'new' template
  end

  def create
    @movie = Movie.create!(params[:movie])
    flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} was successfully created."
    redirect_to movies_path
  end

  def edit
    @movie = Movie.find params[:id]
  end

  def update
    @movie = Movie.find params[:id]
    @movie.update_attributes!(params[:movie])
    flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} was successfully updated."
    redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
  end

  def destroy
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @movie.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Movie '#{@movie.title}' deleted."
    redirect_to movies_path
  end

end
```

I am very very new to Rails, and have been stuck on just this one point for like 4 hours trying different things.

Comment: Where is `@ratings` being defined?  I don't see it anywhere so `@ratings.keys` would give you that error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's walk through that error message...

```
undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass
```

There are three important pieces to this:

1. `undefined method` - This is telling you the core problem. The problem is that the method you're trying to call does not exist for the thing that you're trying to call it on.
2. `keys` - This is telling you the method that you're attempting to call.
3. `nil:NilClass` - This is telling you what you're calling the method on. In your case, this bit of information isn't *directly* helpful - it's not telling you exactly what to look for. It *is* telling you, however, that whatever you're looking for has a value of `nil`.

`Rails.root: C:/Sites/RailsProjects/hw2_rottenpotatoes`

This is telling you the root of your project, just in case you've completely forgotten what you're even working on. It's ok. We all have those days.

```
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:24:in `block in index'
app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:23:in `each'
app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:23:in `index'
```

This is telling you *exactly* where to look for the error that you're hitting. It's right there in the second line: `app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:24` ... File `movies_controller.rb`, line `24`.

It's probably referring to this line:

```
if @ratings.keys.include? mv[:rating]
```

You're checking to see if `mv[:rating]` is in `@ratings.keys` ... But the error that you got is telling you that you're checking for `keys` on `nil`. That means that `@ratings` hasn't been set.

So, it looks like you'll just need to set `@ratings` somewhere near the top of that `index` action.